# Monad instance for Associative Computations Tree

Tags: haskell, tree, monads

I have data type of Associative Computations Tree

```
data EvalATree b a = Leaf a | Node ([b] -> a) [EvalATree b a]
```

Wrote Functor and Applicative for this type

```
instance Functor (EvalATree b) where
  fmap :: (a -> c) -> EvalATree b a -> EvalATree b c
  fmap f (Leaf a) = pure (f a)
  fmap f (Node g trees) = Node (f . g) (fmap (fmap f) trees)

instance Applicative (EvalATree b) where
  pure :: a -> EvalATree b a
  (<*>) :: EvalATree b (a -> c) -> EvalATree b a -> EvalATree b c
  (Leaf f) <*> (Leaf x) = fmap f (Leaf x)
  (Leaf f) <*> (Node g trees) = Node (f . g) (fmap (fmap f) trees)
  (Node g trees) <*> (Leaf x) = Node (g <*> pure x) (fmap (<*> pure x) trees)
  (Node g trees) <*> (Node f otherTrees) = Node (g <*> f) (zipWith (<*>) trees otherTrees)
  pure = Leaf
```

How can i make Monad type class instance for this tree?

I try

```
instance Monad (EvalATree b) where
  return :: a -> EvalATree b a
  (>>=) :: EvalATree b a -> (a -> EvalATree b c) -> EvalATree b c
  (Leaf a) >>= f = f a
  (Node g trees) >>= f = Node (g >>= f) (fmap (>>= f) trees)
  return = pure
```

But i cant unwrap f to get type "c".
Expected: type [b] -> c

Comment: This seems similar to the classic `ZipList` Applicative which is an example of an Applicative that has no Monad instance. So, I don't think it is possible to define a Monad instance for `EvalATree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EvalATree b` has no `Monad` instance that’s compatible with this `Applicative` instance, for the same reason as [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList): given two inputs with different lengths, combining them by zipping will truncate the longer one. So the `Monad` instance isn’t associative—depending on how computations are grouped, you can get different results. A zippy `Monad` instance is valid only if the inputs are always the same shape—such as a fixed-length vector/tuple, or an infinite stream.

However, I think this tree type may not be quite what you want anyway. I assume you wanted `Node f ts` to represent taking the results of the computations `ts`, and giving them as inputs to the function `f`. But there’s no connection between the result type `a` and the input type `b`, without further assumptions about `b`. Your `Applicative` instance doesn’t offer a way to make an `EvalATree b a` that actually uses the `[b]`.

So it’s hard to say what you should do without more context, but here are some suggestions for things to try.

- Just skip writing a `Monad` instance. You can still use `do` notation with `ApplicativeDo`.
- Change the `Applicative` instance to use a Cartesian product, like lists.
- Make `Applicative` and `Monad` instances with some constraints, such as `Monoid b`.
- Get rid of the type parameter `b`, merging it with `a`.

  ```
  data EvalATree a = Leaf a | Node ([a] -> a) [EvalATree a]
  ```
- Use `[a]` or `Monoid a => a` instead of `EvalATree b a`.

Comment: I will try changing the type to get [a] -> a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your applicative seems similar to the classic `ZipList` applicative which is an example of an applicative that has no monad instance. So, I don't think it is possible to define a monad instance for `EvalATree`.

And even if you would define the applicative differently [like the Tree data type from containers does](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.7/docs/src/Data.Tree.html#line-161):

```
instance Applicative (EvalATree b) where
  pure = Leaf
  Leaf f <*> x = fmap f x
  f <*> Leaf y = fmap ($ x) f
  Node g xs <*> Node f ys = Node (g <*> f) [x <*> y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

Then you'd still essentially be composing the Tree monad with the Reader monad which seems impossible to me.

You could consider changing to tree transformers like [TreeT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-1.4/docs/Hedgehog-Internal-Tree.html#t:TreeT) (for some reason not in a standalone package). You'd get a type like this:

```
data EvalATree b a = Leaf a | Node ([b] -> (a, [EvalATree b a]))
```

But I don't know if that matches the behavior you want.